# How to create and use an Oracle transaction

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a stored proc that delete data from two tables.
Should either of the deletes fail I want to make sure that no data was deleted.

This should be a simple task, but I never worked in Oracle before.
I'm not if I should be using TRY/CATCH, TRANSACTIONS or SAVEPOINTS.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Currently I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_DELETE_STUFF 
(
  GROUPNAME IN VARCHAR2  
) AS 
BEGIN

  SAVEPOINT Original_Start;

  -- First delete all permissions for a given group
  DELETE FROM my_table_1
  WHERE group_name = GROUPNAME;

  -- Second delete the group
  DELETE FROM my_table_2
  WHERE group_name = GROUPNAME;

  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT Original_Start;
      COMMIT;  
    END;
  END
```

Comment: You have the right idea, however, I probably wouldn't use that final COMMIT. You've isolated your logic (good), you've put your own save point (ok), and used it properly (good) ... however, by doing that final COMMIT, you going to commit the partial work from somewhere else, ie from whatever called your routine ... Note, that you may not even need to use savepoints (they're handy, and you've basically used them properly), but you may not NEED them here ... so that might simplify things as well.

Comment: to add to my above point, you could probably get this functioning properly without savepoints by doing the following: 1) remove the initial `SAVEPOINT Original_Start;`   2) remove `COMMIT;`  3) change `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT Original_Start;` to just `ROLLBACK;` 4) consider adding `RAISE;` after the `ROLLBACK;`  5) consider adding `COMMIT;` after the 2nd DELETE, before the EXCEPTION (but maybe not if this is called from elsewhere and you want to handle commit by the caller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is just to rollback the changes that a particular call of the stored procedure has made if there is an error, you'd use a `savepoint` and a `rollback to savepoint` like you are doing here.

I would question your use of a `commit` after your `rollback to savepoint`.  That will commit the transaction that the caller of your stored procedure had started.  It seems unlikely that you want to commit the caller's changes when your procedure encounters an error.  So I would expect that you want to remove the `commit`.

Not related to transaction scoping, I would also expect that you would want to at least re-raise the exception that you caught so that the caller is aware that there was a failure.  I would expect that you would want something like

```
 EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT Original_Start;
      RAISE;  
    END;
```

Comment: Maybe add something about naming the `SAVEPOINT`?  You want to make sure that you choose a name that is unlikely to be re-used by anything you call.  "Original_Start" would be a little too common to be safe, I think.